# Why phone requires password after reboot even setting none?

Tags: android, security, encryption, android-source, qualcomm

When I set PIN from Security -> Screen Lock and click "Require PIN to start device", everything works as excepted. Here is the log filtered with "QSEECOMAPI"

```
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0xa000
D QSEECOMAPI: App is already loaded QSEE and app id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0xa000
D QSEECOMAPI: App is already loaded QSEE and app id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 4
E QSEECOMAPI: SUCCESS::ioctl call to update the encryption key for usage 4 success with ret = 0
```

After, when I select Screen Lock "None" again, it still asks PIN after reboot, and here is the log filtered with "QSEECOMAPI" after selected "None"

```
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0xa000
D QSEECOMAPI: App is already loaded QSEE and app id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0xa000
D QSEECOMAPI: App is already loaded QSEE and app id = 4
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_dealloc_memory 
D QSEECOMAPI: QSEECom_shutdown_app, app_id = 4
E QSEECOMAPI: Error::ioctl call to update the encryption key for usage 4 failed with ret = -1, errno = 22
```

So, the last statements in logs shows that it is about libQSEEComAPI.so binary file. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following patch solved my problem..
https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/platform/frameworks/base/commit/?id=09fd281f006779d6c2f126126e69772d35a9fcc0